# Laravel: Renombrar un archivo situado en /resources

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo archivos guardados en la siguiente ruta: `/resources/views/projects/nombreproyecto.blade.php`

Entonces, tengo un formulario que pido el nuevo nombre del proyecto y lo que quiero hacer es renombrar el archivo, por ejemplo:

Tengo un proyecto llamado lluistestantes, pues la ruta al archivo sería la siguiente:
`/resources/views/projects/lluistestantes.blade.php`

Entonces relleno el formulario, y pongo como nombre lluistestdespues, la ruta al archivo debería de ser la siguiente:
`/resources/views/projects/lluistestdespues.blade.php`

El controlador que hace la función se ve así:

```
public function updateProject(Request $request, $id) //Actualizar la informacion de un proyecto 
    { 
       $project = Project::find($id); //Encuentro que proyecto es

            $oldSlug = $project->slug; //guardo el valor ANTIGUO en la variable

            $project->order = $request->input('order'); //no es importante
            $project->public = $request->input('public'); //no es importante

            if (strcmp($oldSlug, $request->input('slug')) !== 0) { //Si el slug cambia, entra en el IF

            Storage::disk('projects')->move($project->slug, $request->input('slug')); //Se renombra la carpeta project, no darle atención a esta linea porque es independiente a la funcionalidad que busco ahora, ademas que es para archivos situados en Storage.

            $project->slug = $request->input('slug'); //se pilla el valor del slug NUEVO

            $project->pathheader = $request->input('slug').'/header.jpg'; //se guarda el path en la bbdd, no darle atención a esta linea porque es independiente a la funcionalidad que busco ahora.

            $project->pathhome = $request->input('slug').'/home.jpg';  //se guarda el path en la bdd, no darle atención a esta linea porque es independiente a la funcionalidad que busco ahora,

            File::move('/resources/views/projects/'.$oldSlug.'.blade.php','/resources/views/projects/'.$project->slug.'.blade.php'); //FUNCIÓN REALMENTE IMPORTANTE, pillo la blade antigua y la intento machacar con el nuevo valor.
        }
    }
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

`rename(/resources/views/projects/lluistestantes.blade.php,/resources/views/projects/lluistestdespues.blade.php): No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No encuentra el archivo porque no le estás pasando toda la ruta donde está ubicado el archivo. Para solucionar eso podes utilizar el helper `resoure_path()` o `base_path('resources')`
Modificá la ultima linea del metodo

```
File::move(resource_path('views/projects/').$oldSlug.'.blade.php',resource_path('views/projects/').$project->slug.'.blade.php');
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que agregues una descripcion de tu solucion, para asi hacerla mas entendible al usuario

Comment: Me ha funcionado @MaruAmallo , no sabía que había un helper como el de public_path pero para resources! Gracias, yo también trabajo con Laravel y Vue así que puedes estar atenta a mi perfil ya que las preguntas irán orientadas sobre esos temas.

Comment: Me alegro de haberte sido de ayuda, también tenes uno para el storage `storage_path()`, para la carpeta app `app_path()`, para la carpeta config `config_path()`, para database `database_path()` y claro `public_path()`  
Acá tenes los helpers 
[Helpers Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php)

Comment: Gracias de nuevo, si quieres puedes echarle un ojo a mi nueva pregunta. Al mezclar Vue con Laravel, hay cosas que aun me pierdo un poco. Ahora probaré con los helpers. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/99719/mostrar-imagen-de-storage-como-background @MaruAmallo

Comment: ahi te respondí. Igual hay muchas formas de hacerlo.
Suelo chequear la etiqueta [laravel] asi que podrías agregarla a tus consultas y cuando revise las preguntas la veo