# Mostrar imagen de Storage como background

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

Ahora mismo tengo el código que se ve de la siguiente manera, accedo a la carpeta assets, que hay dentro de public:

```
<div class="itemProjectImage"  :id="'itemProjectImage_'+i" :style="'background-image:url(/assets/img/projects/'+project.slug+'/home.jpg'">
</div>
```

Lo que me gustaría sería acceder directamente a storage, pero con vue:

```
<p class="lead"><img src="{{ asset('/storage/employees/'.$employee->slug.'/'.$employee->slug.'.'.'jpg') }}" width="50%" ></p>
```

¿Cuál sería la manera correcta?

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurren muchas formas de hacer esto pero todo depende de lo que requiera el sitema, confidencialidad de la imagen etc.

```
// Ruta
Route::get('images/{filename}', 'ImagenesController@imagen'); // Deberias de usar un middelware `->middleware('auth')`


// controlador

    public function imagen($slug)
    {
        $path = storage_path() . '/employees/' . $slug .'jpg'; // Podés poner cualquier ubicacion que quieras dentro del storage

        if(!File::exists($path)) abort(404); // Si el archivo no existe

        $file = File::get($path);
        $type = File::mimeType($path);

        $response = Response::make($file, 200);
        $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

        return $response;
    }

// en el componente

<template>
    <p class="lead"><img src="'/imagen/${this.employee.slug}'" width="50%" ></p>
</template>
```

Otra opcion puede ser que conviertas la imagen a base64 en el controlador y retornás un string y podés llamarla desde el componente mediante ajax

```
methods: {
    getImage(slug) {
        var imagen = ''
        axios.get(`/imagen/${this.employee.slug}`)
            .then(function(response) {
                imagen = response.data
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                fail(error)
            })
        return imagen
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Maru, gracias de nuevo. Hay algo que no entiendo, y es el porque tener que hacer una ruta, etc etc. Tengo archivos blade, en los cuales accedo a imagenes de la siguiente manera, por ejemplo: `<img src="{{ asset('/storage/employees/'.$employee->slug.'/'.$employee->slug.'.'.'jpg') }}" width="50%" >` , en vue no se puede y es necesario hacer todos estos pasos de tu respuesta?

Comment: el helper `asset()` es para la carpeta `public`. Si vos queres almacenar archivos en `storage` tenes que llamarlos mediante una ruta. Tené en cuenta que esta carpeta es para informacion que no está disponible para todo el mundo

Comment: Tal vez mi duda es mas de 'sintaxis', ahora mismo estoy intentado acceder de la siguiente manera: `<div class="itemProjectImage"  :id="'itemProjectImage_'+i" :style="'background-image:url({{asset('/storage/projects/'+project.slug+'/home.jpg')}}'">` pero me da un error.

Comment: Pero si tengo un symbolic link en la carpeta public que lo enlaza con storage (que es mi caso), no estaría correcto? Quiero decir, la ruta que te he puesto en el primer comentario funciona bien, y realmente es una llamada como tu dices a la carpeta public ya que utilizo asset, pero es al symbolic link.

Comment: No, te explico. En el primer comentario que pongo el: `img src="{{ asset('/storage/employees/'.$employee->slug.'/'.$employee->slug.'.'.'jpg') }}" width="50%" >` sí estoy en una blade. En el de ahora estoy en un archivo .vue

Comment: Estas dentro de un componente o de una vista blade?
Si estas en un compomenete los helpers de blade no te sirven  
Si estas en una vista de blade no podes usar variables vue dentro del helper, al menos no asi. Se me esta complicando ponerte la solución ya que no uso vue en las vistas pero se que hay que agregarle un `@` `@{{ variable}}`

Comment: En el archivo .vue se ve así la línia: `<div class="itemProjectImage"  :id="'itemProjectImage_'+i" :style="'background-image:url({{asset('/storage/projects/'+project.slug+'/home.jpg')}}'">` pero me da syntax error. Voy a chequear tu ultimo comentario a ver si veo el syntax error.

Comment: ok, dentro del componente vue no podes usar los helpers de laravel. por eso te tira error

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65115/discussion-between-lluis-puig-ferrer-and-maru-amallo).

Comment: hola Maru, estas?

Comment: Hola, si, estoy. Escribime en el chat

Comment: Estoy en chat :) @MaruAmallo

Answer (score 0):

solo necesitas configurar una ruta en laravel por ejemplo:

```
Route::get('myRoute/{myImage}','myController@anyThing');
```

en la etiqueta image lo haces asi:

```
<img :src="'myRoute/myImage.jpg'">
```

si tu controlador funciona con eso bastara, espero que te funcione suerte con tu proyecto.